# Dynamics CRM 2011 - How I should install my custom entities when installing or deploying my solution

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am trying to do a solution which has custom entities and should create some basic data when it is installed by first time, let's say that is going to install some data in 'Roles'.
How I shoul achieve it? I am making code to create this custom entities, but I do not know when execute this code. I saw that there is other way making the custom entities by code or using the UI of solutions, then export it (the solution with the entities are exported) whith that I can import it again to deploy my solution.

Can somebody point me in the right way?

Comment: So you are creating new entities that will live with in the CRM system? Or just creating new data for existing objects in the system?

Comment: Actually I didn't understand your question very well. If you want to import solution and keep data. You have to import the entities first, and then import the data.

Comment: I need both, create custom entities and add data but just the first time (Like a common installer does).

Answer (score 3):

To clear up any confusion of terms here:

- Entities: This is a customization of CRM. An entity is to CRM, what a table is to SQL - they dont actually represent any data in themselves. Entities can be included in solutions.
- Records: These are pieces of data that populate entities (or tables). These cannot be included in solutions.

When you say 'Roles' I assume you are referring to the 'Security Roles', these can be included in solutions.

You can (and should) use a solution file to move all customisations from one environment to another.

These are all the parts that can be included in a solution (taken from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334576.aspx)).

[image]

For all your records (or data) you will have to import these manually. CRM has out of the box features for data import, or you could script it with some web service calls.

So in this case I believe you need to:

1. Create your solution in your development environment.
2. Import it as a managed solution into your production environment.
3. Perform a data import to setup any system/configuration records/data.

For a better overview of solutions I would suggest having a read of the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334530.aspx).

Edit (based on comment):

---

Re: 1 - You need to build a solution for your customisations and entities. When you export the solution all the customisations are included automatically in the XML files, you can then import the solution as a whole into another system.

If you dont know how to create a solution watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxkBMi_ZO_U).

Re: 2 - Do the data import manually once you have imported the solution.

If you dont know how to do a data import watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yi64Uk3MqXE).

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I have two doubts:
1. Related to the 2nd step, How I should import my 'Custom entities' througth an XML file (I saw a file named customizations which host custom entites in XML format when you export a solution), or I should do it by code? (As the 'entities' sample in the SDK 'samplecode' folder)   . 2. Which is the moment when I can perform the 3rd step you metioned? I come for programming for desktop I would hope execute this step when my solution is imported in some CRM.  Thanks so much for helpping.

Comment: Thanks, for the first question I conclude that the only way to add custom entities when import my solution is first create a solution, create my custom entities (by codding or UI), export my solution and then importing solution to other CRM’s. For the second question I was hopping away to do that by code (or at least as the first question), and just once time (when the solution is imported) Do you know a way not manually? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Crm does not have the ability to package data with a solution, so you will have to do that as a second step. You could code a solution import and data import to stream line that process.